# Parse file and group content between tags

Tags: php, arrays, file, parsing

I'm trying to **parse a file** that has the following structure:

```
Page: name of page

Lang: language
{1} content of a header
{2} content of a paragraph

Lang: language
{1} content of a header
{2} content of a paragraph


Page: name of page
Lang: language

{1} content of a header
{2} content of a paragraph
```

and so on.

I fetch such content from the cloud, save into a file and then I want to fetch each page as **an associative array** in the form:

```
page => page 1
    [lang] => language A
        [1] => content of a header
        [2] => content of a paragraph
    [lang] => language B
        [1] => content of a header
        [2] => content of a paragraph
page => page 2
    [lang] => language A
        [1] => content of a header
        [2] => content of a paragraph
    [lang] => language B
        [1] => content of a header
        [2] => content of a paragraph
...
```

I've been trying to build the entire array from the file and then start to group by tags, but I've been having no success. :/

Comment: @bažmegakapa Just read the file as an entire array, cleaning the empty items, and looping it for exploding each line that has the tag `Page` or `Lang` taking its value before and after `:`.

Comment: And what went wrong? We can't really write this whole thing for you. But if you show us what you tried, and which are the weak points, we could help you fix it.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I don't wait any code. Just ideas about possible ways of building such data structure. What I've done is not wrong, it's just not enough since the entire array I actually have is not grouped ny page, neither by language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the following approach:

1. fetch the file as an entire array, using each line as an element
2. search for the first coincidence with the page used, ie., the string after 'Page:'
3. get the elements betw such coincidence and the following page
4. loop the resultant array grouping by 'Lang' as key

Since I'm working with PHP, used functions are: `file()`, `array_search()`, `array_slice()`.